# Unable to animate with insertBefore jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using HTML5 list. I want to add new 'li' dynamically with animation.I have used an insertBefore function.Any idea how can I animate list with slide effect(Horizontal widget list).

Answer (score 1):

try with updated answer

```js
$("<li>Test</li>").insertBefore(".inner").hide().toggle('slide');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li>Greetings</li>
  <li class="inner">Hello</li>
  <li class="inner">Goodbye</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know insertBefore but I want to add with slide effect please understand the question properly.

Comment: I have horizontal list, not vertical @Bhargav

Comment: I have implemented drag drop functionality and into that I need this just to make smooth movement

Answer (score 1):

try this

little bit modification in @Bhargav's answer

hope it will help :)

```js
$("<li style='display:none'>Test</li>").insertBefore(".inner").slideDown();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li>Greetings</li>
  <li class="inner">Hello</li>
  <li class="inner">Goodbye</li>
</ul>
```